# how exactly rtmfp / UDP works

Tags: udp, protocols, p2p, flash-media-server, rtmfp

I am trying to develop a live video chat app using flash and rtmfp protocol but I have doubts as to 
how rtmfp guarantees to connect peers especially when the peers are located in different networks.

Comment: RTMFP and Skype *punch holes* in firewalls: http://www.h-online.com/security/features/How-Skype-Co-get-round-firewalls-747197.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

RTMFP relies on a central rendezvous server to "introduce" 2 clients that are in different networks and potentially behind firewalls. To navigate through firewalls it uses [NAT traversal techniques](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NAT_traversal) which essentially amounts to:

- 2 clients (Joe, and Mary) connect to central rendezvous server

  - Adobe's public RTMFP (non-commercial) rendezvous server rtmfp://p2p.rtmfp.net/
  - Or you can host your own using the GPL Open Sourced [Cumulus](https://github.com/OpenRTMFP/Cumulus) or [ArcusNode](https://github.com/OpenRTMFP/ArcusNode)
- Joe shares his peer ID with Mary or they can use a shared [NetGroup](http://www.flashrealtime.com/simple-chat-p2p-netgroup-rtmfp/) ID
- Mary communicates with the central rendezvous server which then uses a variety of NAT and Firewall traversal techniques to establish a peer 2 peer UDP connection

There is no guarantee that any 2 clients networks/firewalls are compatible for RTMFP P2P connections (you can diagnose with the [RTMFP connection tester](http://blog.yoz.sk/2010/07/rtmfp-connection-tester/)), that's why Adobe provides fallback solutions through their [LiveCycle Collaboration Service](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flashplatform/services/collaboration.html) or [Adobe Flash Media Server](http://www.adobe.com/products/adobe-media-server-extended/rtmfp-faq.html) to a central relay service (basically all network traffic would pass through a Server that both clients can publicly access) if a direct P2P connection can't be established.

Adobe's RTMFP is their proprietary bundling of Peer 2 Peer network rendevous service, as well as providing some other higher level P2P network mesh features.

If you're interested in a more open standard P2P protocol you should look into [WebRTC](http://www.webrtc.org/). Essentially WebRTC is the same concept of allowing clients to connect P2P over UDP but geared towards being adopted as a web browser standard, and can also be implemented on a variety of native devices (e.g. Android, iPhone etc) under the hood it uses standard NAT and firewall traversal technology using [STUN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/STUN), [ICE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interactive_Connectivity_Establishment), [TURN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Traversal_Using_Relays_around_NAT), [RTP-over-TCP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real-time_Transport_Protocol) and support for proxies. I believe WebRTC is a standardization of some of the work done in the [libjingle](http://code.google.com/p/libjingle/) P2P Google Talk library.